# Should the "Related Questions" list include questions from Stack Overflows sister sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, stack-exchange

With the release of Server Fault and Super User I just thought I would throw this up in the air.

Would it make sense to include other questions from SO's sister sites to try and avoid the migration of questions that might belong or are already on those sites?

Comment: good idea (15 char)

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know there is no plans to integrate the sister sites, however a suggestion regarding this has been made [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration).

Comment: Your link is broken. Any chance you could come up with something similar to fix it?